# A question about combined improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose that $f(x)$ is **continues** in the open interval $(a,b)$ and suppose that 
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
$$
is one of the following **combined improper** integrals:

**(1)** $a=-\infty$ and $b=\infty$.

**(2)** $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=\pm\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

**(3)** $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=\pm\infty$ and $b=\infty$

**(4)** $a=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=\pm\infty$

In addition, suppose that $F(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $f(x)$ in $(a,b)$.

Is it true that if at least one of $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}F(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}F(x)$ is finite, then
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{x\to b^{-}}F(x)-\lim_{x\to a^{+}}F(x)
$$

**EDIT**: I meant in the assumption that both of the limits are finite *or* one is finite and the other one is infinite.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have results for integrals that are improper at only one boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this ...
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\;dx
$$
with $f(x) = 2 e^x \sin x$ and $F(x) = e^x(\sin x - \cos x)$.
This is case $(1)$, with $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0$.  But $F(x)$ oscillates wildly as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks #GEdgar. Is the claim still true if both of the limits are finite? is it true when one is finite and the other is infinite ? I edit my question

Comment: For case where both limits exist in $\mathbb R$, this is the definition of improper integral.  For the case where one exists in $\mathbb R$ and the other is $\pm \infty$, you will have to check the definition of improper integral in your particular textbook.